# How to make column data unique for each user_id in ruby on rails

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, unique

The problem is that I have a table customers with some customers related columns like customersID.
Also I have a column `user_id` So that the customers data only relate to one user.

```
class Customers
belongs_to :user
end

class Users
has_many :customers
end
```

Now I have the :unique on the customersID. But this makes every customerID unique all over the table.
What i want is that the customerID is unique per user_id.

Any idea or suggestions?

Edit: Question seems bit unclear.

I have a table users

```
user1
user2
user3
```

also i have a table customers where each customer get a user_id from the user who created him. The user can input a customerID, which should be unique for each user.

```
customerID=1 user_id1
customerID=2 user_id1
customerID=1 user_id3
customerID=3 user_id1
customerID=1 user_id2
...
```

I crud the customers data via `@customers = current_user.customers` in my CustomersController. The customerID is a simple `t.integer  "customerID"`

Comment: Errr... I'm not sure if got the whole picture but... Why don't you just use `belongs_to :customer` and `has_many :users` then?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you want a Customer to have a User, is that correct? Try something like this:

```
class Customer
  has_one :user
end

class User
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

That way you can have a customer tied to one specific user_id. Then you could do something like this:

```
@customer = Customer.where(name: "company name").first
@user = @customer.user  #this will find the customer's unique user
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not force uniqueness of the pair Customer_id, iser_id via an index on your Customers table ? You could create a migration something like

add_index_to_costumers.rb

```
class AddIndexToCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :customers, [:customerID,:user_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

It should ensure at the database level that the pair customerID/user_id is unique. If I well understand your question it's what you expect.

Hope this helps

Cheers

Comment: So every `customerID` would be uniq. What I want is that for each user the `customerID` count from 1 to infi and is unique. Hope made it clear